# How to query many to many polymorphic relation with specific class type?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I've created tables: `addresses`, `contacts`, `events` and `addressables`.

Here `addressables (id, address_id, addressable_id, addressable_type)` has many to many polymorphic relation for address with `contacts` and `events`.

I've defined following models:

Address:

```
class Address extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [...];

    public function addressable()
    {
        $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

Contact:

```
class Contact extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [...];

    public function addresses()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Address::class, 'addressable');
    }
}
```

Event:

```
class Event extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [...];

    public function addresses()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Address::class, 'addressable');
    }
}
```

Now I wanted to fetch all addresses by contact or event or any other models defined. Is it possible to fetch addresses by specific type without defining following functions in `Address` model? Any help is much appreciated.

```
public function contacts()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('Contact', 'addressable');
}


public function events()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('Event', 'addressable');
}
```

If possible how could I achieve the solution?

Expected:

```
$contactAddress = Address::getAddressable('App\Contact');
$eventAddress = Address::getAddressable('App\Event');
```

Comment: Why don't you want to define `contacts()` and `events()`?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Because, there can have other models that would be using address. So I wanted those functions to be dynamically calculated for any model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `addresses` relationships:

```
$contactAddress = Contact::with('addresses')->get()->pluck('addresses')->flatten();
```

As a separate method:

```
class Address extends Model
{
    public static function getAddressable($class)
    {
        return $class::with('addresses')->get()->pluck('addresses')->flatten();
    }
}
```